# MySQL's FROM_UNIXTIME only supports 10 digit unix time representations. Not 13 digit ones.

Tags: mysql

Is there a MySQL function that converts timestamps to a `datetime`. I tried the following:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1337951145000);
```

But it returns null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your timestamp is too long, try

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1337951145);
```

Or

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1337951145.000);
```

Answer (score 1):

The maximum representable time is 2038-01-19. At 03:14:07 UTC, you timestamp is over that.

Answer (score 1):

Your timestamp is valid ok.

Currently, timestamps are either 10 or 13 digits. 13-digit Timestamps (such as yours) have an additional 3-digit microseconds.

But to my (Google's) knowledge, MySQL's functions only supports the short 32bit timestamp (and you are [not the only one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762288/why-does-mysql-unix-time-stop-short-of-the-32-bit-unsigned-integer-limit) to hit this wall.

Hopefully they'll sort it out before 2038.