# MySQL FROM_UNIXTIME command not writing

Tags: c++, mysql, sql

Here is my SQL query I am running:

```
string theQuery = "UPDATE readings SET chng = 1, time = FROM_UNIXTIME(";
theQuery += boost::lexical_cast<string>(ss.time);
theQuery += ") WHERE id = 1;";
```

ss.time is a uint32_t that records the number of seconds since 1 Jan 1970. When I attempt to put the value "3586767203" into the brackets of FROM_UNIXTIME, which is the time value on my device, it updates my time field to NULL. If I enter a smaller number it updates the time field fine.

Why is it updating to NULL if I am entering a valid time??

Comment: Your problem explained: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762288/why-does-mysql-unix-time-stop-short-of-the-32-bit-unsigned-integer-limit

Comment: This can't be the best way to compose this string. Would streams help? They should do implicit conversion. Also, 3586767203 is Aug. 29th, 2083, which is way outside the range of 32-bit unixtime.

Answer (score 0):

You've exceeded the limits of UNIXTIME. 3586767203 is 'Sun, 29 Aug 2083 12:13:23 GMT' and UNIXTIME can't be bigger than a date that resolves into '2038-01-18 22:14:07' ( FROM_UNIXTIME(2147483647) ) because the time is stored as a signed 32 bit integer of seconds after the epoch (Jan 1, 1970) and 2^31 seconds after the epoch is 'Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:08 GMT'.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem for an explanation of this problem.