# How to Get UTC Datetime from UNIX_TIMESTAMP() in MySQL

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I want to know that how to get utc datetime from unix_timestamp in mysql.

But, I should not use CONVERT_TZ.

(because Could not use timezone function in partitioning.)

The error occurs in the SQL schema...

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `idx` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  etc...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
PARTITION BY RANGE( YEAR(CONVERT_TZ(from_unixtime(`idx` >> 24), @@session.time_zone, '+00:00')) )
SUBPARTITION BY HASH ( MONTH(CONVERT_TZ(from_unixtime(`idx` >> 24), @@session.time_zone, '+00:00')) )
SUBPARTITIONS 12 (
    PARTITION p2016 VALUES LESS THAN (2016),
    PARTITION p2017 VALUES LESS THAN (2017),
    PARTITION p2018 VALUES LESS THAN (2018),
    PARTITION p2019 VALUES LESS THAN (2019),
    PARTITION p2020 VALUES LESS THAN (2020)
)
```

Comment: Please see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-timestamp

Comment: Sorry ... mistake...
UTC_TIMESTAMP is UNIX_TIMESTAMP..

Comment: `idx` colume's most significant 40 bits are UNIX_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: `SUBPARTITION` and `BY HASH` are almost always useless; what was the purpose in using them?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is not `CONVERT_TZ`, but `FROM_UNIXTIME`.

`FROM_UNIXTIME` takes an Integer as argument - which means 32 bit.

If you take todays unix-timestamp: `1480546792`, shifted right 24 bit - you are just exceeding the 32-bit limit for a valid parameter on `unix_time`.

`from_unixtime` can only handle parameters upto `2147483647` - Which means, it works up until `2038-01-19 04:14:07`

I've encountered this problem as well, and since 2002 a fix for this is "under development".

Until it has finally be resolved, you should use a workaround, using `date_add`. Instead of

```
from_unixtime (x)
```

use

```
date_add(from_unixtime(0), INTERVAL x second)
```

Result(s):

```
SELECT from_unixtime (2147483647); //2038-01-19 04:14:07 
SELECT from_unixtime (2147483648); //NULL

SELECT date_add(from_unixtime(0), Interval 2147483647 second) //2038-01-19 04:14:07
SELECT date_add(from_unixtime(0), Interval 2147483648 second) //2038-01-19 04:14:08
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
but my `idx` colume format is (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() << 24 + other number[24bit]).
Just i want to partitioning by year and month.

Comment: @user212942 can you provide an example value for `idx`, where it fails?

Answer (score 0):

You are in a bind here.  *Whenever* you render a `TIMESTAMP` data item as a date / time item, MySQL implicitly converts it from UTC to local time(where local time is controlled by current connection's `time_zone` setting.

That makes it infeasible to use `YEAR(timestamp)` to control partitioning. Pretty much anything you do with [MySQL date and time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to extract the year will perform the conversion.  That means any such conversion will be nondeterministic. That means you can't use it to control partitioning.

You could use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP() DIV ( 365 * 24 * 60 *60)` or some such approximation of years to control your partitioning. It would be close, inexact, and deterministic.

Or you could use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP() DIV 16777216` or `UNIX_TIMESTAMP() >> 24` for partitioning.  That's 2 ^ 24. It's a little over 194 days. It's arbitrary. But if years are good partitioning breaks, so are these time periods. And, you're already using a bitfield model in your indexing.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks for your answer~